# Definite bug in Android Studio regarding Spinners and the `clickable` attribute?

Tags: android-studio, android-spinner, clickable

In my app, I want to make my spinners `clickable=true` or `clickable=false` at different times. But, despite setting the attribute both in the Attributes Inspector and in code, Android Studio simply does not respect the `clickable` attribute.

[image: Android Studio Attribute Inspector Clickable]

(I do NOT want to enable/disable the spinners, because that changes the way they are displayed, ie. greyed out.)

Here's a bare-bones project to show....

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerA"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:entries="@android:array/organizationTypes"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerB"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:entries="@android:array/imProtocols"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinnerA" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.heewhack.clickablespinners

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        spinnerB.isClickable = false
    }
}
```

This seems to be a major bug in Android Studio...

Questions:

1. Can someone confirm my findings, or better yet, show me what I'm missing?
2. Does anyone know a work-around?
3. Can I change the way enabled/disabled items are displayed?
4. How should I report this bug, if it's actually a bug?

Comment: Ok, I found the answer to #4. In the Help menu, I've selected "Submit Feedback"

Comment: I've tested this both in the emulator (API 27) and on a physical device (API 27).